# How do I access parseFloat inside an angular factory function named parseFloat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, global

How do I access parseFloat inside an angular factory function named parseFloat?

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('mathService', [MathService]);

function MathService() {
    return {
        parseFloat: parseFloat
    };

    function parseFloat(num) {
        // this should be the global parseFloat 
        // and not the this math service parseFloat
        return parseFloat(num, 10); // how do I fix this line?
    }
}
```

Currently this causes infinite recursion.  How do I access the global parseFloat inside this factory method called parseFloat?

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question but I would suggest avoiding creating your own function named after javascript functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.parseFloat(num, 10)` should work.

Comment: I wasn't the person who downvoted, but personally, instead of downvoting the answer (which is valid and correct, so +1 from me) I would have downvoted the question, because, as a "best practice", should always avoid: (1) JavaScript Reserved Words, (2) JavaScript Objects, Properties, and Methods, (3) Java Reserved Words, and (4) Windows Reserved Words. [http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)